# Is there some library to help writing instrumentation like measuring the execution time of the methods

Tags: c#, .net

Any library which can assist those tasks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Stopwatch class

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
   {
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    stopWatch.Stop();
    // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

    // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);
    Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
}
```

}

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp) - [Performace Counters](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/performance)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a profiler - I think it is available only in the Pro edition and above. IT works nicely in general.

If you have more specific or particular needs you may want to look into PostSharp or other add-ons.